# Ubuntu Access Denied

Tags: 20.04

I am running the Ubuntu 20 on Windows 10.
I was trying to add a directory to my path variable by editing .profile
However, I can only do this from the command line and I was unable to do this using `gedit ~/.profile` due to the error:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:76): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:57:16.278: cannot open display:
```

So, I did something I now regret.

```
echo export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/add >> ./profile
```

I did make a copy of the ./profile beforehand. But when I restarted Ubuntu, I got "Access Denied"

Any help would be appreciated.

@GunnarHjalmarsson

Comment: So this is Windows Subsystem for Linux, or a VM?  If it's WSL, this is As Expected, currently WSL1 does not support GUI compatibility without a LOT of work for GUI apps

Comment: instead of `gedit` try the command with `nano`

Comment: This was using Windows Subsystem for LInux. Thanks for your comments. I went ahead and reinstalled thinking my data would remain. Fortunately, the reinstall fixed the Access Denied issue; unfortunately, all my data was lost. :(

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend any new Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL) users to read through this great users guide: https://github.com/michaeltreat/Windows-Subsystem-For-Linux-Setup-Guide/

Section 3 dealt with my issue:

> Ubuntu Files
> Now that you are in your Ubuntu User's root, type ls -a
> to show all hidden files. Notice that you have a .profile file. This
> is where your terminal's profile settings are stored. This is also an
> Ubuntu file because it is on the Ubuntu FS. You can't edit this file
> through Windows, or a Windows program or app, as it wouldn't work. You
> might see the changes show up in the file, but it will not be read
> correctly anymore. In the off chance that you do need to edit a Ubuntu
> file then you should use the built in code editor called nano, or use
> the CLI to install a different one. Just remember that you cannot use
> a GUI here, so you must edit Ubuntu files through the command line.

Good to know:

> IMPORTANT: Anytime you uninstall the app and reinstall it you will
> lose any data that lives on the Linux Filesystem. This inlcudes
> databases, configs, .profile's, and anything else you might have
> stored on the NON-Windows Filesystem. Make sure to back this data up!
>
> ...while Ubuntu can read and write both Ubuntu and Windows files,
> Windows can only read and write Windows files, and read Ubuntu Files,
> but it cannot write Ubuntu files. Knowing which files belong to which
> FS is important because of this.

In hindsight, to edit ~/.profile, @db429 was right, one should use the nano command.